# can I specify how I want the output in valgrind?

Tags: c, valgrind

I am working on a very big c program and am trying to find out memory leaks in it. The output that I get from valgrind is very huge around 80000 lines(containing all types of errors) which is very hard to manage to check line by line.
What I want is that I get the outputs of valgrind only when there is a definitely lost or possibly lost leaks and no other errors so that I can rectify things by focusing on these two errors. Is it possible then please tell me?

Comment: all errors from valgrind are errors. Start from top, fix that then continue.

Comment: Of course that is what I  am doing right now. But if there is a way I can manipulate how I see the output do tell.

Comment: Apparently the manual page is also too huge to read. But you may want to take a look at `--show-leak-kinds`. Your actual problem is that you don't appear to have a build and test environment. Maybe look at ValgrindCI for some inspiration.

Comment: If you only want to look at leak errors, you can use --undef-value-errors=no to disable some errors. What you can also do is to have a suppression file that suppresses the errors you do not want to handle. The suppression entries should be so that they match any stack trace for the error kind given in the entry. But as mention in the first comment, all errors should  by default be analysed and fixed.

Comment: Like I have code in many files say in src directory i have 3 other directory namely common, vcom , code which contain many c files. If i want the errors that are in common file only. Is that possible?(I think i can use suppression but i have never used them before and cannot get an idea so please tell if possible)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are many options to control the output. You may want to consider running Valgrind in some kind of GUI if that makes it easier for you to process errors. Qt Creator and Valkyrie spring to mind (I have no experience with Valkyrie). You might also want to consider either the xml output or the xtree format (for use with kcachegrind).

Start with  `--show-leak-kinds=definite`, and work your way through the errors. In my experience, unless the code is systematically bad, you will find that just fixing a small number of errors will dramatically reduce the number of errors that Valgrind reports.